# Relative to approximation and Taylor expansion of $f^{"}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

The problem asks for the highest value of $p$ such that:

$f^{"}(x)$ = $\frac{f(x - h) - 2f(x) + f(x + h)}{h^{2}}$ + $O(h^{p})$

Using the following:

- Method of undetermined coefficients: $f^{"}(x)$ $\approx$ $Af(x + h) + Bf(x) + Cf(x - h)$
- Taylor expansion of $f(x + h)$ and $f(x - h)$: $f(x \pm h) = f(x) \pm hf^{'}(x) \pm \frac{h^{2}}{2}f^{"}(x) \pm \frac{h^{3}}{6}f^{(3)}(x) \pm \frac{h^{4}}{24}f^{(4)}(x) $

I arrived at the following:

$f^{"}(x)$ = $\frac{f(x - h) - 2f(x) + f(x + h)}{h^{2}}$ - $\frac{h^{2}}{12}f^{(4)}(c)$ with $c ∈ (x - h, x + h)$

With that I concluded $O(h^{p}) = O(h^{2})$. But the problem asks for the highest value of p. So am I correct saying that $p = 2$ or am I too naive here?

Comment: What about when $ f^{(4)}$ unbounded at $(x-h,x+h)$.

Comment: You mean when $f^{4}$ is not a constant? How do we handle that case? How many terms should we use in the Taylor expansion?

Comment: What assumptions about $f$ do you have? As long as $f^{(4)}$ is continuous on some neighborhood of $0$, then you can bound $f^{(4)}$ by a constant on this interval, and then the error term is $O(h^2)$ as $h \to 0$ by your work.

Comment: I mean, for any $M>0$, and any $ h>0$, there exist $ a\in(x-h,x+h) : |f^{(4)}(a)|>M$.

Comment: @angryavian I assumed the derivative can be written as a linear combination of the values of the function at certain points, and I arrived at what I showed above. But the question asks for the highest value, so I don't know if my assumptions are reasonable.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah That's a good point. What do we arrive at in that case then?

Comment: You have also assumed that the 4th derivative exists. hamam_Abdallah is pointing out that this is not enough to ensure $f^{(4)}$ is bounded near the origin. My comment is pointing out that as long as $f^{(4)}$ is continuous on an interval near the origin (which would be true if, say, you assume the 5th derivative exists), then $f^{(4)} is bounded near the origin.